# Get value providing column header as variable in Excel

Tags: excel

I’m looking for way in Excel to retrieve a value from a table by providing the row index as a number and the column name as a string variable.

Here is an example:
[image]

`INDEX` was close but it is not accepting column names as variables.

Is that even possible in Excel? I am looking for a solution without VBA.

Comment: You probably want to combine the `INDEX` with [`MATCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment; indeed `MATCH` was the goal. In B10 my formula is:

```
=INDEX(A1:D4,B7,MATCH(B8,A1:D1,0))
```

retrieving 420.